# node-gyp how to configure it with a compiler who support C++ 11

Tags: raspbian, node.js

I'm trying to to install a module with npm, but when node-gyp is trying to rebuild, it says that the mod I'm trying to install need a C++11 compiler.
I have actually no idea how to change the compiler nor how can I know with which version node-gyp is compiling with.

Any idea? Thanks

**EDIT**

I finally resolved my problem:
My gnu compiler was 4.6 version, switching to 4.9 resolved it.
After installed g++4.9, my problem was setting it as my default compiler. (node-gyp was still using 4.6).

So

```
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++4.9 50
```

In order to link g++4.9 to g++.

Then

```
sudo update-alternatives --config g++
```

To select one of the alternative. In my case, there was only g++-4.9.

Then a sanity check:

```
g++ --version
```

Which returned 4.9.2 for my case. 
node-gyp could then compile all the dependency with the right compiler.

Comment: Please cut n' paste the exact error, the output of `cat /etc/issue`, and the *last line* of `g++ -v`.   If the last one returns "no such command", try `sudo apt-get install g++`.